# xmpp: 2 clients with same account

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

is it possible to connect to the same server (ejabberd) with same account 2 or more clients?
if yes - how to do this with pyxmpp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to connect to an XMPP account from multiple clients (unless this is explicitly turned off on the server). They just need to make their `resource` field distinct. Something like (not tested):

First client:

```
pyxmpp.jabber.client.JabberClient(jid=pyxmpp.jid.JID("johny", "example.com", "home"), ...)
```

Second client:

```
pyxmpp.jabber.client.JabberClient(jid=pyxmpp.jid.JID("johny", "example.com", "work"), ...)
```

Also, some servers (f.e. gmail) will give your connections unique resources automatically. Some not.